# ExtJs5.1 - Nested Panels: resize inner panels to outer panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, resize

### Problem Description

I got some ExtJs5.1 code, which has a couple of **nested components**, like *Ext.form.field.TextArea*, *Ext.tab.Panel* and *Ext.Button*.

You can *copy&paste* the following code to reproduce my problem into a **index.html** file and experiment with it (assuming you have a local-webserver running and copied the ExtJs5.1 files into the htdocs folder of the webserver, for example like Xampp):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>

    <link id="theme1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>

    
    
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady( function(){
    
            var textfield = 
                Ext.create('Ext.form.field.TextArea', {
                                title: 'textfield',
                                autoscroll: true});
            
            var textfield_2 = 
                Ext.create('Ext.form.field.TextArea', {
                                title: 'textfield_2',
                                autoscroll: true});
                                
            var tab_panel = 
                Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
                                title: 'tab_panel',
                                columnWidth: 0.5,
                                padding: '10 10 10 10',
                                items:[textfield, textfield_2]  
                            });
            
            var right_panel = 
                Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                                title: 'right_panel',
                                columnWidth: 0.5,
                                html: 'blablabalablablaba3',
                                padding: '10 10 10 10'
                            });
            
            var lower_vbox_panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                title: 'lower_vbox_panel',
                frame: true,
                autoscroll: true,
                layout: {type: 'column'},           
                margin: '10 10 10 10',
                items: [tab_panel,right_panel]
            });
            
            var button_1 = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                text: 'button_1',
                padding: '15 15 15 15',
                margin: '10 10 10 10',
                handler: function() {
                    console.log('button_1 click!');
                }
            });
            
            var button_2 = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                text: 'button_2',
                padding: '15 15 15 15',
                margin: '10 10 10 10',
                handler: function() {
                    console.log('button_2 click!');
                }
            });
            
            var upper_vbox_panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                title: 'upper_vbox_panel',
                margin: '10 10 10 10',
                frame: true,
                items: [button_1, button_2]
            });
            
            var vbox_panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                frame: true,
                title: 'vbox_panel',
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                autoscroll: true,
                margin: '15 15 15 15',
                layout: {type: 'vbox', align: 'stretch'},
                items: [upper_vbox_panel,lower_vbox_panel]
            });

            textfield.setValue("blablablablabla");
            textfield_2.setValue("blablablablabla2");
        
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

After resizing the browser-window, the outer panel named **vbox_panel** does resize automatically to fit the browser-windows' width and height.

Unfortunately, the two nested panels named **upper_vbox_panel** and **lower_vbox_panel** together with their nested components do not resize with respect to the outer panel named **vbox_panel**.

### Question:

**How can the two nested panels also be resized with respect to the outer panel named *vbox_panel*?**

### EDIT:

I found out that the class **Ext.container.Viewport** is used to fit containers to the browser-window, so the outer panel named **vbox_panel** must be added to it:

```
var vp = new Ext.Viewport({
    layout : 'fit',
    items : [vbox_panel] ,
    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```

Now the width of every nested component is changing after resizing the browser-window, but the height of them is not.

I have searched half the internet on solutions, including things like: layout: 'anchor', align:'stretch' etc. pp.. But none of them work.

### New Question after edit:

**How to incorporate the change of browser-window-height into the nested components?**

Answer (score 0):

Use [layout:'fit'](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Fit) to match the base container to its parent, in this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/n8u) you could see the layout configs in action.

Please read the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/core_concepts/layouts.html) to get a better understanding, in-short parent layout is responsible for positioning and sizing of all of its children.

Comment: But when i set layout to 'fit', i can not use layout 'column' in base container anymore.